# What does Ezekiel 17:24 refer to? Who are the people or kingdoms spoken of

Tags: ezekiel

In Ez 17:24 The high tree is Possibly the kingdom of Israel but I would like to know who is referred to as:-
Low tree,
Green tree,
Dry tree.

> **Ezekiel 17:24** All the trees of the forest will know that I the Lord bring down the tall tree and make the **low tree** grow tall. I dry up the **green tree** and make the **dry tree** flourish.
> “‘I the Lord have spoken, and I will do it.’”

Comment: Trees are references to people, in this case high trees are kings or royalty. A low tree is a non royal blood or a commoner, green tree is a prosperous person and a dry tree a poor person or lacking resources

Comment: This is fully explained in the text.  Numerous commentaries explain this fully such as >> https://biblehub.com/commentaries/cambridge/ezekiel/17.htm

Answer (score 1):

To understand this riddle **you have to differentiate between!**:

- "**the house of Israel**" - who the riddle is directed/addressed to (**Israelites!**) - see Exekiel 17:2
- "**the remnant of the house of Judah**" - who the riddle is about (**Jews!**)

The **'house of Israel'** *(the **10** tribes which came to make up the northern kingdom of Israel)* was taken into Assyrian captivity many years prior to the events portrayed in this "parable". - see 2 Kings 18:9-11

The **'house of Judah'** *(the **3** tribes which came to make up the southern kingdom (more specifically, Jerusalem))* at the time of this riddle had recently been subjugated by the king of Babylon. And the king in Jerusalem is reaching out to the king of Egypt for military assistance to regain their sovereignty.

Since God has arranged for the Babylonian captivity of the residue of the house of Judah, He is very displeased with Jerusalem's attempt to undercut His will/plan and is going to diminish/overturn Jerusalem and to strengthen/bring back the house of Israel to prominence.

> **Ezekiel 17**   <sub><sup>22</sup></sub>Thus saith the Lord GOD; I will also take of the **highest branch**<sup>**1**</sup> of the **high cedar**<sup>**2**</sup>, and will set it; I will crop off from the **top of his young twigs**<sup>**3**</sup> a **tender one**<sup>**4**</sup>, and will plant it upon an **high mountain**<sup>**5**</sup> and eminent:  <sub><sup>23</sup></sub>In the mountain of the height of **Israel**<sup>**6**</sup> will I plant it: and it shall bring forth boughs, and bear fruit, and be a goodly cedar: and under it shall dwell **all fowl of every wing**<sup>**7**</sup>; in the shadow of the branches thereof shall they dwell.    <sub><sup>24</sup></sub>And all the **trees**<sup>**8**</sup> of the **field**<sup>**9**</sup> shall know that I the LORD have brought down the **high tree**<sup>**10**</sup>, have exalted the **low tree**<sup>**11**</sup>, have dried up the **green tree**<sup>**12**</sup>, and have made the **dry tree**<sup>**13**</sup> to flourish: I the LORD have spoken and have done it.

**<sup>1</sup>highest branch** - symbolic of the king in Jerusalem (of the line of David?)

**<sup>2</sup>high cedar** - symbolic of Jerusalem (residue of the house of Judah)

**<sup>3</sup>top of his young twigs** - symbolic of royal family

**<sup>4</sup>tender one** - symbolic of young heirs *(daughter(s)?)* of the king

**<sup>5</sup>high mountain** - symbolic of a prominent nation/peoples

**<sup>6</sup>Israel** - synonymous with house of Israel (who the riddle is being "put forth" to)

**<sup>7</sup>all fowl of every wing** - symbolic of those from every kingdoms/nations/peoples

**<sup>8</sup>trees** - symbolic of nations/peoples

**<sup>9</sup>field** - symbolic of the world

**<sup>10</sup>high tree** - symbolic of house of Judah

**<sup>11</sup>low tree** - symbolic of house of Israel

**<sup>12</sup>green tree** - symbolic of house of Judah

**<sup>13</sup>dry tree** -symbolic of house of Israel

It would appear that God is transferring the remaining heir(s) of the line of kings in Jerusalem *(the line of David?)* to transplant them into the house of Israel wherever they are located at that time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the context. Ezekiel 17:

> 22“ ‘This is what the Sovereign Lord says: I myself will take a shoot from the very top of a cedar and plant it; I will break off a tender sprig from its topmost shoots and plant it on a high and lofty mountain. 23On the mountain heights of **Israel** I will plant it; it will produce branches and bear fruit and become a **splendid cedar**.

Israel is associated with the splendid cedar.

> **Birds** of every kind will nest in it; they will find shelter in the shade of its branches.

It would bless all kinds of birds/peoples.

> 24 All the **trees** of the forest will know that I the Lord bring down the tall tree and make the low tree grow tall. I dry up the green tree and make the dry tree flourish.

Trees symbolize different kingdoms. God has the power to do as he wills as in Luke 1:52

> He has brought down rulers from their thrones,
> And has exalted those who were humble.